# Help with Ruby & PrinceXML

Tags: ruby, princexml

I'm trying to write a very simple markdown-like converter in ruby, then pass the output to [PrinceXML](http://princexml.com) (which is awesome). Prince basically converts html to pdf.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# USAGE: command source-file.txt target-file.pdf

# read argument 1 as input
text = File.read(ARGV[0])

# wrap paragraphs in paragraph tags
text = text.gsub(/^(.+)/, '<p>\1</p>')

# create a new temp file for processing
htmlFile = File.new('/tmp/sample.html', "w+")

# place the transformed text in the new file
htmlFile.puts text

# run prince
system 'prince /tmp/sample.html #{ARGV[1]}'
```

But this dumps an empty file to `/tmp/sample.html`. When I exclude calling prince, the conversion happens just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the file output is being buffered, and not written to disk, because of how you are creating the output file. Try this instead:

```
# create a new temp file for processing
File.open('/tmp/sample.html', "w+") do |htmlFile|

  # place the transformed text in the new file
  htmlFile.puts text

end

# run prince
system 'prince /tmp/sample.html #{ARGV[1]}'
```

This is idiomatic Ruby; We pass a block to `File.new` and it will automatically be closed when the block exits. As a by-product of closing the file, any buffered output will be flushed to disk, where your code in your `system` call can find it.

Comment: I get the following warning: `File::new() does not take block; use File::open() instead`

Comment: Yes, that'd be correct. I'll tweak the answer to reflect reality.

Comment: I'm starting to think that there are two bugs at once here: buffered output and trying to do string interpolation inside single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

From the [fine manual](http://princexml.com/doc/7.0/command-line/):

> prince doc.html -o out.pdf
>   Convert doc.html to out.pdf.

I think your `system` call should look like this:

```
system "prince /tmp/sample.html -o #{ARGV[1]}"
```

Also note the switch to double quotes so that `#{}` interpolation will work. Without the double quotes, the shell will see this command:

```
prince /tmp/sample.html #{ARGV[1]}
```

and then it will ignore everything after `#` as a comment. I'm not sure why you end up with an empty `/tmp/sample.html`, I'd expect a PDF in `/tmp/sample.pdf` based on my reading of the documentation.

Comment: Hmmm... I've been using Prince for years and I've never once used the `-o` flag. It seems to have no effect. And, yes, the big problem is that with the `system` call the script creates an empty file, but without it the script processes the file as expected.

Comment: @Oliver: Does using double quotes on your `system` call make a difference? And what if you flush or close `htmlFile` before `system` as Tin Man suggests?

Comment: I changed it to doubles, and no, it didn't make a difference. And, yes, what @theTinMan suggested worked perfectly.

Comment: @Oliver: But does it pay attention to `ARGV[1]` without the double quotes or does it just produce `/tmp/sample.pdf`?